# Não consigo fazer com que meu programa calcule o troco pra 100 nas notas que meu cliente põe. Em C

Tags: c

Preciso de um programa que calcula o troco pra uma nota de 100 reais. Ele pede pra entra com quais notas eu quero o troco e assim calcula quantas notas de cada eu preciso pra trocar 100. Os números precisam ser sempre inteiros . Se entrar 0 primeiro, deve solicitar outro valor. Os valores precisam sair em ordem crescente. (ex. ENTRADA 10 20 - SAÍDA 20 20 20 20 10 10) Não consigo desenvolver a lógica pro algoritmo separa a quantidade certa de cada célula. Se alguém puder ajudar eu ficaria muito grata, estou desesperada já haha. Qualquer ajuda é válida. :) Comecei tentando os valores individuais que precisa de cada nota pra atingir 100, mas não evolui.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int n, i, j, troco, n2=2, n5=5, n10=10, n20=20, n50=50, qn2, qn5, qn10, qn20, qn50;

printf("Digite o número da variedade de notas: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

int vet[n];

printf("Digite o valor das notas: \n ");

for(i=0, i<n; i++){
   scanf("%d", vet[i]);
  
}

for(j=0; j<n; j++){ \\ troco individual de cada nota para torcar 100
    if(vet[i]==n2){
        qn2 = (100/ vet[i]);  
    }if(vet[i]==n5){
        qn5 = (100/ vet[i]);  
    }if(vet[i]==n10){
        qn10 = (100/ vet[i]);  
    }if(vet[i]==n20){
        qn20 = (100/ vet[i]);  
    }if(vet[i]==n50){
        qn50 = (100/ vet[i]);  
    }
    
}


return 0;
```

}

Comment: Note que sua solução não tem sentido. Se o valor informado para n for 2 e você informar 10 para vet[0] e 20 para vet[1] então obterá 10 para qn10 e 5 para qn20 que serão quantidades que não condizem com o resultado esperado. Você não definiu como compor o resultado, diz que, para a entrada exemplo, a saída seria 20 20 20 20 10 10 mas por quê não 20 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ou ainda 20 20 20 10 10 10 10? Ou qualquer resposta será aceita?

Comment: Então, n deverá ser a quantia da variedade, ou seja, se eu quero meu troco em notas de 10 e 20, então meu n deve ser 2.Eu pensei em ler as notas, guardar no vetor e depois ler o tamanho dele também. O resultado deve sair em ordem crescente. A intenção do n2, n5, n10 e assim sucessivamente é saber o valor do troco individual de cada valor para 100, para 10 reais eu tenho 10 notas para atingir 100, para 20 reais eu tenho 5 notas de 20 para atingir 100 e assim vai. Eu comecei pensando assim pra ver se evoluía na lógica sabe, usar como recurso de resolução e não como saída.

Comment: Você precisa pensar mais na solução. Por exemplo você aceita qualquer entrada mas se a entrada for 20 50 não existirá solução possível com **ambas** as notas.

Comment: Nesse caso eu imprimo uma mensagem. É uma condição inclusive, mas a dificuldade tá mesmo em fazer a contagem. Estou tentando aqui, quem sabe, fé. :)

Comment: Pense matematicamente, para cada valor vi informado deve existir uma quantidade qi, maior que zero, tal que o somatório dos qi*vi seja 100.

Answer (score -1):

É quase o que deseja, adapte para a saída no formato desejado.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n, i, j, troco, notas[5]={2, 5, 10, 20, 50}, qtd[5]={0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, soma;

    printf("Digite o número da variedade de notas: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int vet[n];

    printf("Digite o valor das notas: \n ");

    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &vet[i]);
        while (vet[i] == 0) {
            printf("Valor inválido. Reinforme: ");
            scanf("%d", &vet[i]);
        }
        j = 0;
        while ((j < 5) && (notas[j] != vet[i]))
            j++;
        if (j < 5)
            qtd[j] = 1;
        else {
            printf("Valor de nota (%d) inválido\n", vet[i]);
            return -1;
        }
    }
    for (j=0; j<5; j++)
        printf("\t%d\t%d\n", notas[j], qtd[j]);
    troco = 100;
    do {
        soma = 0;
        for (j=0; j<5; j++)
            soma += notas[j]*qtd[j];
        if (soma < troco) {
            for (j=4; j>=0; j--) {
                if (qtd[j] != 0)
                    if ((soma + notas[j]) <= troco) {
                        qtd[j]++;
                        j = -1;
                    }
            }
        } 
    } while (soma < troco);
    if (soma == troco) {
        for (i=4; i>=0; i--)
            if (qtd[i] > 0)
                printf("Nota: %d\tQuantidade: %d\n", notas[i], qtd[i]);
    }
    else {
        printf("Impossível compor o valor\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigadaa!